# Homotopy classes of maps

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, reference-request, gt.geometric-topology

This is a reference request.

A theorem of Hurewicz (published in *Beiträge zur Topologie der Deformationen. IV. Asphärische Räume*, Proc. Akad. Wetensch. Amsterdam, volume 39, deel 2 (1936), 215-224, [digitised version](http://www.dwc.knaw.nl/toegangen/digital-library-knaw/?pagetype=publDetail&pId=PU00016845)) asserts $\left[X,Y\right]=Hom(\pi_1X,\pi_1Y)/Inn(\pi_1Y)$ for aspherical spaces.

The generalization to arbitrary (pairs of) spaces reads: when $f,g:(X,X_1)\rightarrow (Y,Y_1)$ are such that $f_\ast=g_\ast:\pi_i(X)\rightarrow \pi_i(Y)$ and $f_\ast=g_\ast:\pi_i(X_1)\rightarrow \pi_i(Y_1)$ for all $i$, then $f$ and $g$ are homotopic (as maps of pairs).

I think I know how to prove this for pairs of CW complexes. My question is just for a citable reference either in a paper or a textbook.

Comment: BTW the theorem of Hurewicz you mention is explained nicely in Appendix 4.A of Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology" text.

Comment: Detecting homotopic maps by means of homotopy groups is a very complicated task. There are even conjectures on it, look up 'Freyd generating hypothesis'.

Comment: At least homotopy classes from X to K(G,1) correspond to homomorphisms of fundamental groups mod inner autos.

Comment: Just a note: that journal is hard to find, but if your library subscribes to Elsevier you may have access to it, but under a different name.  See https://plus.google.com/115215145654669548294/posts/jHJTaqaB5e2

Comment: @Charles that link is now useless, so I added a link to the digitised version of the paper, or at least what I think is the paper. There is another 1936 Hurewicz paper in (what is now) Indag. Math., namely [this](http://www.dwc.knaw.nl/toegangen/digital-library-knaw/?pagetype=publDetail&pId=PU00016834), but it nowhere mentions aspherical spaces.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think this is true. For a counter-example take $f$ to be any pointed map $K(G,n)\to K(H,m)$ representing a non-trivial cohomology operation, where $G$ and $H$ are abelian groups and $m>n>1$. Then $f$ and the trivial map $g$ induce the same map on homotopy groups, but are not based homotopic.